# Displaying a directed graph in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, graphics, graphviz

How can I display a directed graph in Ruby on Rails?

Basically, I'm looking for something like graphviz for Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ruby-graphviz` gem - https://github.com/glejeune/Ruby-Graphviz

Comment: Thanks! One question: Under which OSes does it (painlessly) work? I'm experimenting with Rails on a Windows machine, but my site is hosted on a linux machine.

Comment: It should work with Linux/Mac. On windows it says `On Windows you also need to install win32-open3. This is not an absolute requirement.`. Search 'windows' in the readme.

Answer (score 2):

If you don´t want to use Graphviz, you could also have a look at JavaScript libraries for visualization, e.g. [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)